# How to get all rows from left table if there are two left join

Tags: mysql

I have added two left join in a mysqli query , I need all rows from first table audit_form_tbl.

```
SELECT qt1.field_id
     , qt1.type
     , qt1.parent_id
     , qt1.field_type
     , qt1.field_name
     , qt1.required
     , qt1.maxlength
     , qft1.field_value
     , qt1.can_be_na
     , qft1.form_id
     , avtf.type_variable 
  FROM audit_form_tbl qt1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN audit_variables_tbl avtf 
    ON qt1.audit_variable_id = avtf.id 
  JOIN audit_form_value_4_tbl qft1 
    ON qt1.field_id = qft1.field_id 
 WHERE qt1.field_id = qft1.field_id 
   AND qt1.type IN ('F') 
   AND avtf.company_id IN ('4', 0) 
   AND qt1.company_form_id = '23' 
   AND qft1.form_id = '4231578043277' 
   AND qt1.parent_id = '' 
   AND qt1.status = 1 
ORDER 
   BY qt1.sort_order ASC
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dxnZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eqCF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo3gK.png)

Audit form tables has some rows which has not inserted in audit_value_tbl . I only getting rows which has been inserted in audit_value_tbl table.

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: @forpas added the full query

Comment: You did not post  sample data and expected results so your question is still unclear.

Comment: @forpas Please check screenshot

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT qt1.field_id
     , qt1.type
     , qt1.parent_id
     , qt1.field_type
     , qt1.field_name
     , qt1.required
     , qt1.maxlength
     , qft1.field_value
     , qt1.can_be_na
     , qft1.form_id
     , avtf.type_variable 
  FROM audit_form_tbl qt1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN audit_variables_tbl avtf 
    ON qt1.audit_variable_id = avtf.id 
   AND avtf.company_id IN (4,0) 
  LEFT -- <-- obviously, omit this if you want an INNER JOIN here
  JOIN audit_form_value_4_tbl qft1 
    ON qt1.field_id = qft1.field_id
   AND qft1.form_id = '4231578043277' 
   AND qt1.field_id = qft1.field_id 
 WHERE qt1.type IN ('F') 
   AND qt1.company_form_id = 23 
   AND qt1.parent_id = '' 
   AND qt1.status = 1 
ORDER 
   BY qt1.sort_order ASC
```

Comment: problem is, not all qt1.field_id has been inserted in audit_form_value_4_tbl

Comment: And that's a problem because...?

Comment: no I still need not inserted fields , its not a problem